# Convergence of maximal sum implies the sum converges

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_i$'s be i.i.d., and suppose $\max_{1\leq k\leq n}S_k/n\to 0$ a.s. Does it imply that $S_n/n\to 0$ a.s.?

Edited: $Sn:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.

My thoughts: The converse is trivial, using directly $\epsilon$-$\delta$ languages. However, in the forward direction, it may happen that $S_n/n<-\epsilon$ infinitely often for some $\epsilon>0$. But since $X_i$'s are i.i.d, this seems not happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just consider $X_i :=-1$ and $$S_n :=1+ \sum_{j=1}^n X_j.$$

Comment: @saz How are those i.i.d.? (You set $X_0=1$, for what reason?)

Comment: That $X_0$ and $X_1$, for instance, are independent but not identically distributed since $X_0=1$ a.s., $X_1=-1$ a.s. @saz

Comment: @ClementC. Well, usually $(S_n)_{n \geq 1}$ has some initial condition $S_1$ and I chose it to be $1$... in the end, the initial condition doesn't matter; $$S_n := \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$$ works as well.

Comment: @saz Yes, hence my question "for what reason" :)

Comment: @saz Thank you. Could you elaborate more on the “initial conditions?” By the way, I edited my question so that Sn becomes the usual definition.

Comment: @ThomasYang It's not exactly the usual definition, but it doesn't really matter. As I already suggested in my first comment, $X_j := -1$ shows that the assertion does, in general, not hold true.